# Checking a RadioButton

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to check a radio button, I am new to c++ and MFC so after some search I wrote :

```
INT m_nIndex;

CButton* pButton1 = (CButton*) GetDlgItem(IDC_RADIO1);
CButton* pButton2 = (CButton*) GetDlgItem(IDC_RADIO2);

pButton1->SetCheck(m_nIndex == 0);
pButton2->SetCheck(m_nIndex == 1);

    if (pButton1.IsChecked){ //Here pButton1 shows an error saying expression much have a class type
    }
```

- What can I do to call the radioButton?
- Another Question, how to put a radioButton checked by default?

Comment: Isn't pButton1->SetCheck(m_nIndex == 0); calling the radio button?

Comment: `pButton` is a pointer type, that needs to be dereferenced before you can access its members. Either use `(*pButton1).IsChecked` or `pButton1->IsChecked` (assuming that `IsChecked` is a class member). Apart from that, [CButton::SetCheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31deb72x.aspx) expects an integer argument. Trying to learn C++ with MFC isn't going to end well. Learning MFC without a solid understanding of C++ isn't going to end well either.

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1889329).

Comment: So you advice me to learn c++ without MFC first?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/34zhkbc/9 Not working @ IInspectable

Comment: That's hardly surprising. It's certainly not one of the options I suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` is solved by this:

```
    if (IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_RADIO1))
    {

    }
```

I just call `SetCheck` in my initializer to set up my radio buttons. Not sure if this is what you mean by default

Comment: Thank You .. It helps me in the if statement.. But what I meant in default that when runnig I want the radiobutton1 be pressed

Answer (score 0):

To set the default radio button use the following method of `CWnd` class:

```
CheckRadioButton(int nIDFirstButton, int nIDLastButton, int nIDCheckButton);
```

Also I'd suggest using `pButton->GetCheck()` to get the current radio button state. You can also use it for check boxes.